# Reports as PDF in Access 2007 using a Stored Procedure

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am creating a report in Access 2007 and am able to save it as a PDF, but the problem is that instead of having 1 report per PDF I have got 206 Reports in 1 PDF. I'm using VBA to programatically do this 
here is the code I'm using

```
Sub makeLetterPDF(Contract As String, LetterType, outTo As String)

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strReportName As String
Dim strFileName As String
Dim Maxrow As Integer
Dim C As Integer

Dim fileno As Integer

    SysCmd acSysCmdSetStatus, "Saving " & C & " of " & Maxrow

    strReportName = LetterType

    strFileName = LetterType & fileno & ".PDF"

    fileno = fileno + 1

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strReportName, acFormatPDF, _
                    outTo & "\" & strFileName, , , , acExportQualityPrint ``"
    SysCmd acSysCmdSetStatus, " "

End Sub

Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

Dim strRecordSource As String

    strRecordSource = "Exec dbo.rsp_Letter_ServiceBooking '" & Contract & "'"
    Me.RecordSource = strRecordSource

End Sub
```

The report open has the Stored Procedure that has the data I need for the report but how do I iterate through this to create the individual reports as the `makeLetterPDF` is run first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i sorted it buy changing the way i got the data and only getting one record at a time this works